# Concern about missing attribute using JSoup in a Login

Tags: java, parsing, web, html-parsing, jsoup

The website I'm trying to login and parse using JSoup doesn't have an attribute called "name" in the inputs.

How can fill the input fields and submit the form in other way?

```
<form id="login_form">
   <div class="row">
      <label for="mobile_phone">E-mail:</label>
         <div class="input_error_wrapper">
           <input class="input required" id="e-mail" type="text" style="background-color:transparent;">                               
         </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <div class="input_error_wrapper">
            <input class="input required" id="password" type="password" style="background-color:transparent;">
          </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row clear_fix">
       <input class="submit_btn fl_right" type="submit" value="enter">
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some JavaScript files on this site that send data from this form. You can find function in this JS that is triggered by submit_btn and find out the way data is sent.

Comment: I've kinda of that: -  $('#login').on('click', '.submit_btn', function() {
  var email_or_phone  = $('#login_form #e-mail').val();
  var password        = $('#login_form #password').val();
  $.post(RETAIL_URL+'/login', {email_or_phone : email_or_phone, password : password}, function(data) {
    $('#login .login_error').hide();
    if (toInt(data.status)) {
      window.location.href = ( data.hasOwnProperty('url') ? data.url : RETAIL_URL );
    } else {
     $('#login .login_error').text(data.message).show();
    }
  });
  }
  return false;
});
}

Comment: So You can just send json  '{email_or_phone : email_or_phone,password : password}' to this url 'RETAIL_URL+"/login"'